# How to setup Paxton Net2 client and server

Tags: software-installation, wine

Being new to Ubuntu and looking for the stability that Linux offers, I am looking to set up:

- Paxton Net2 client and server
- Hikvision iVMS4200 client
- Texecom software (I already got this one working.)

There are no official versions of the ivms client for Ubuntu. I tried the unofficial one, and it does not work on the newer cameras and NVRs.
Paxton Net2 software is only available for Windows, and with Windows 10 being as unstable as it is I need to have a unit that will run continuously. I would prefer to not use any VM software, but if I must I will use it.

I have tried winetricks, but Ubuntu I haven't gotten it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Because net2 uses SQL Server Express it is going to be very difficult to get it working on a Linux system.

In theory you might be able to use SQL Server 2017 for Linux. Here's a link to MS's instructions for Ubuntu: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017

Assuming you can get that working the next challenge will be to get the net2 server components installed and running under wine. Again I think that might be a challenge as its a mix of MFC and .NET and no one planned for it to work with .net core at the time.

Most probably you will end up having to put it in a virtual machine which I know you want to avoid. Then again, the server only needs to run during configuration so if you don't issue cards all the time or re-configure the site you could install the server on a windows laptop or in a VM and use it once in a while to configure the ACUs and the system will run happily on it's own....